# Laptop does not resume on lid opening: how to identify the issue?

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on a Dell laptop. My computer used to behave as expected on closing and opening the lid: suspend and resume.

Since a few weeks, that functionality is broken, it does not resume (or correctly suspend) anymore. The fan remains blowing and the laptop light keeps blinking.

I presume some modification has broken it because before it was working fine. I wonder whether there are log files that indicate what makes the computer not resume correctly.

Comment: Can you update both the BIOS for the computer and also the Ubuntu Power Management driver?  These are the first two things I would try